# C# Get List Ids Inserted With SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dbcontext

I use net core to api controller and Client with React.
I want get details of list opportunity after insert to DB but I do not knowHow get list ids of data added?

#### My Code Insert Data.

```
   var customers = await db.Customers.Where(c =>
    c.Categories.Any(cate =>
     model.CustomerCategories.Contains(cate.CategoryId)
    )
   ).ToListAsync();

   foreach(var customer in customers) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name)) {
     opportunityName = customer.FullName;
    }
    var opportunity = new Opportunity {
     StepId = model.StepId,
      Name = opportunityName,
      Email = customer.Email,
      Phone = customer.Phone,
      CustomerId = customer.Id,
      Status = IdentityStatus.Active,
      ExpectedRevenue = model.ExpectedRevenue,
      Probability = model.Probability,
      Notes = model.Note,
      Deadline = model.Deadline,
      OwnerId = OwnerId,
      Reason = model.Reason,
      Revenue = model.Revenue,
      CompleteDate = model.CompleteDate,
    };
    db.Opportunities.Add(opportunity);

   }
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Keep track of the entities you are adding, call `SaveChangesAsync` and then inspect them afterwards. EF will have populated their keys.

Comment: The first thanks for your reply but i'm newbie c# .Can you explain more in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the entities you are adding, call `SaveChangesAsync` and then inspect them afterwards. EF will have populated their keys.

Here's some psuedo-code that should illustrate the idea:

```
   var customers = await db.Customers.Where(c =>
    c.Categories.Any(cate =>
     model.CustomerCategories.Contains(cate.CategoryId)
    )
   ).ToListAsync();

   var opportunities = new List<Opportunity>(customers.Count);

   foreach(var customer in customers) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name)) {
     opportunityName = customer.FullName;
    }
    var opportunity = new Opportunity {
     StepId = model.StepId,
      Name = opportunityName,
      Email = customer.Email,
      Phone = customer.Phone,
      CustomerId = customer.Id,
      Status = IdentityStatus.Active,
      ExpectedRevenue = model.ExpectedRevenue,
      Probability = model.Probability,
      Notes = model.Note,
      Deadline = model.Deadline,
      OwnerId = OwnerId,
      Reason = model.Reason,
      Revenue = model.Revenue,
      CompleteDate = model.CompleteDate,
    };
    opportunities.Add(opportunity);
    //db.Opportunities.Add(opportunity);

   }

   db.Opportunities.AddRange(opportunities);
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();

   //foreach (var opportunity in opportunities)
     // Console.WriteLine(opportunity.YourIdPropertyHere);
```

Comment: Thank you. have a nice weekend